# Uso della parola "moroso"

Tags: word-usage, regional

**Moroso** sta per *ragazzo, fidanzatino*. Lo si usa molto spesso in Valtellina, l'area d'Italia da cui provengo. 
Mi domandavo se si trattasse solo di una parola dialettale oppure se in qualche altra zona di Italia si usi e se si tratti effettivamente di Italiano!

Comment: L'ho sentito usare in diverse città Emiliane, e forse anche a Milano.

Comment: Anche in Romagna lo usiamo, anche in versione dialettale.

Answer (score 13):

“[Moroso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/moroso1/)” è una normale parola italiana e denota chi è in ritardo con un pagamento (viene dal latino *mora* che significa “indugio”).

L'omonima parola che significa “fidanzato” e simili è un [settentrionalismo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/moroso2/), in parte usato anche fuori del Nord, ma per lo più percepita come locale.

Comment: L'origine della parola come sinonimo di "fidanzato" è una derivazione dell'aggettivo "amoroso" come ho sempre saputo io?

Comment: @LuciaBentivoglio: Sì, la voce del dizionario Treccani che linkavo sopra dà “moroso” come «aferesi di *amoroso*».

Comment: infatti, per lo più nel nord italia! Al sud è molto raro